# How to setup python 3.9 on my windows command prompt? It shows an error python not found

Tags: python, windows

I am trying since many hours, after watching several tutorials and reading many blogs I've setup variables as shown by them. Tried all of their methods to setup python3.9 on my windows cmd, but failed. I'm sharing some screenshots of my system variables and other things, please look into the problem and help me.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is there actually a python.exe in `C:\Python39`? Have you restarted your computer after setting the PATH?

Answer (score 1):

When you want to share on your post the errors you are getting, please insert them using the `Code Sample` function so that we can clearly read your errors and have a clear look at your situation.

Anyways, when you first install Python you have to option to automatically add Python to `PATH`, try uninstalling and checking that option.

If this doesn't work, paste inside your post the error you are getting.

EDIT: Can you share a screenshot of your Python directory?